# How can I extract only certain text from similar elements using BeautifulSoup and Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The site I'm talking about : http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=160

You cannot scrap this site via normal request, it doesn't allow that. Hence, I'm using selenium. Now, my question :

I've been trying to get the TEXT from the 'GENRE' field. As you can see, on page, it shows like this:

```
Genres: adventure, comedy, science fiction
```

The problem with scraping is that these have links attached to them and when I scrap the data, I cannot scrape just the text. It also shows me the classes, links linked to these genres.

My code right now :

```
driver.get('http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=160')

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*")
source_codeANN = elem.get_attribute("outerHTML")
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(source_codeANN, 'html.parser')
Genre = soup2.find_all('div',{'id':'infotype-30'})
print Genre
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the following HTML

```
<div id="infotype-30" class="encyc-info-type br same-width-as-main" style="width: auto;">
    <strong>Genres:</strong> 
    <span><a href="/encyclopedia/search/genreresults?w=series&amp;a=AA&amp;a=OC&amp;a=TA&amp;a=MA&amp;g=adventure/A&amp;o=rating" class="discreet">adventure</a></span>,
    <span><a href="/encyclopedia/search/genreresults?w=series&amp;a=AA&amp;a=OC&amp;a=TA&amp;a=MA&amp;g=comedy&amp;o=rating" class="discreet">comedy</a></span>,
    <span><a href="/encyclopedia/search/genreresults?w=series&amp;a=AA&amp;a=OC&amp;a=TA&amp;a=MA&amp;g=science%20fiction&amp;o=rating" class="discreet">science fiction</a></span>
</div>
```

you can get the values of the genre links like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=160')
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*")
source_codeANN = elem.get_attribute("outerHTML")
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(source_codeANN, 'html.parser')
genre_div = soup2.find('div', id='infotype-30')
genres = [ a.text for a in genre_div.find_all('a') ]
print genres
# [u'adventure', u'comedy', u'science fiction']
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest locating all following siblings of the `strong` element with `Genres:` text and join:

```
", ".join(elm.text for elm in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//strong[. = 'Genres:']/following-sibling::*"))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
>>> driver.get("http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=160")  
>>> ", ".join(elm.text for elm in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//strong[. = 'Genres:']/following-sibling::*"))
u'adventure, comedy, science fiction'
```

Comment: It did the job, thank you. But, could you please explain what happened here a bit?

Comment: @user2408212 sure, first of all, the main problem you had is that you actually needed to get the `.text` of elements you found. Here we are using selenium-only to locate elements using an XPath expression. First we find the `strong` element with `Genres:` text and get all sibling elements after it. Then, using string join to join the texts of the elements we've just found. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ahh.. I get it now. Thank you alecxe. thank you so much for the explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
driver.get("http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=160");
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("infotype-30")
print elem.text
```

Comment: Thanks, but, this seems to be java. I'm not working on java.

Comment: That is most certainly not Python.

Comment: I am sorry, please check it now.